# Printing files in filename order

Tags: vb.net, sorting, printing

I want to print a directory of files in the order of filename ascending (not happening for me - seems to default in file creation order).

Code:

```
Dim PrintPDF As New ProcessStartInfo
For Each fileName1 In Directory.GetFiles(strALPRMailOutReports, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    PrintPDF.UseShellExecute = True
    PrintPDF.Verb = "print"
    PrintPDF.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(fileName1)
    PrintPDF.FileName = strALPRMailOutReports & "\" & fileNameOnly
    Process.Start(PrintPDF)
Next
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx): "The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort method if a specific sort order is required."

Comment: Pardon I'm new at vb coding but can you please give an example of how I would incorporate the Sort into my above code for printing?

Comment: Thank you Cody. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple sort will do the trick.

```
 Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("Path here")
 Array.Sort(files)
 For Each fileName1 In files
     'Print fileName1
 Next
```